# Creating Database Project from Database in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Here are the steps I took:

1. In Visual Studio, I created an ASP.NET MVC application with authentication
2. I specified that the database is an Azure SQL Database living in the cloud

So at this point I have a single project in my solution, the web application project for ASP.NET.  And I have this database created in Azure with my membership database objects.

Now what I want to do is create a **database project** in this same solution for more detailed and in depth database development.

I created a database project, and I can easily set to deploy to Azure but I would be "overwriting" the Azure database that was created initially.

How can I **"refresh"** the database project I just created to reflect the existing database in Azure at this point so I'm not overwriting?

Basically I'm looking to "sync" up the existing Azure SQL Database with the new database project I just created in the solution.

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is the Schema Compare feature from SSDT (Sql Server data tools)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx